# Show list item in list view only for users having contribute permissions, not readonly/View

Tags: 2010, list-view

I have a list having item level permisisons, and not inheritted.

Every item goes through multiple steps, and contribute permission is given to next group, and previous contributors are assigned 'ReadOnly/View' permissions.

The problem here is in the list view, users having 'ReadOnly/View' permissions are also able to see, while I need it to be seen by those currently having "Contribute" permissions. The reason behind this is we have 2 hyperlink type columns, with Edit link and view link. We dont want the users with  'ReadOnly/View' to see the edit link. But they have the View link into an email sent.

Is there a way to acheive. If not possible in list view, I can create a custom page, but the data getting pulled should be visible as per above requirement.

Thanks

Comment: Don't give the previous users readonly / view permissions then? You're breaking permissions anyway so you'd be better off removing permissions for them from the particular item if you don't want them to see instead of jumping through hoops.

Comment: Updated context, previous users require readonly / view permissions to see the details of the item [But not update]